# Approximating $\mathbb{E}(|X^2-Y^2|)$ for jointly normal correlated random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, expected-value, correlation, gaussian

I'm considering the correlated bivariate normal variables

$$\left(\begin{array}{c}X\\Y\end{array}\right)\sim\mathcal{N}\left[\left(\begin{array}{c}4\\2\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&\frac12\\\frac12&1\end{array}\right)\right].$$

The main goal is to find $\mathbb{E}(|X^2-Y^2|)$. I was asked to give interval of possible values. I know that

$$\mathbb{E}(X^2-Y^2)=\mathbb{E}(X^2)-\mathbb{E}(Y^2)=\text{Var}(X)-\text{Var}(Y)+\mathbb{E}(X)^2-\mathbb{E}(Y)^2=12,$$
and this is a lower bound since it includes negative values. From this point on, I am asked to argue that $X>Y$ most of the time is a good approximation. My thoughts are:

- Since the centre of the distribution is a distance of $\sqrt2$ from the line $Y=X$, the region of $X<Y$ approximately $\sqrt2$ standard deviations from the mean.
- Wolfram Alpha says that $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^xf_{XY}\textrm{d}y\textrm{d}x\approx0.977$.

Do these two facts work as justification for $X>Y$, and how do I construct the interval from them?

Comment: Since $U$ and $V$ are independent you could simply use $\mathbb E(\lvert X^2-Y^2\rvert)=\mathbb E(\lvert UV\rvert)=\mathbb E(\lvert U\rvert)\,\mathbb E(\lvert V\rvert)$.

Comment: @nejimban ahh of course! That completely slipped my mind, I'll update the details

Comment: So I would personally go with this approach, using that $$\mathbb E(|N|)=\mu  \,\text{erf}\left(\frac{\mu}{\sigma\sqrt2}\right)+\sigma\sqrt{\frac2\pi}\,\mathrm e^{-\frac{\mu^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$
for $N\sim\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.

Comment: For the record, I found $$\mathbb E\left\lvert X^2-Y^2\right\rvert=\frac{3 \left(2\mathrm e^2\,\text{erf}\left(\sqrt{2}\right)+\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}\right)^2}{\mathrm e^4}\approx12.2046.$$

Comment: Hi, as advised I have reduced it to the approximation part and will ask the remainder  in a separate question